# ORA-02020 – Too many database links in use

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, connection-pooling, dblink

i have a web based application which uses weblogic connection pooling while accessing oracle db. there is a procedure in which i must use db link to fetch and update remote table. but after a few call my service which triggers procedure call i got ORA-02020 – Too many database links in use error.

I think it causes from weblogic connection pool, it does not close session so db link is not closed and it reached max dblink count after a few try.

i've found http://dbtricks.com/?p=198 work around solution but it have not worked for me. i must use db link so what should i do? is there any solution for my case?

thanks.

Comment: DId you checked if you can update the limit ? If you followed the linked page to close them correctly, this could be an simple solution.

Comment: what is value? `select value from v$parameter where name ='open_links'`

Comment: @AxelH, no i can not update the limit.

Comment: @Dmitry Demin, it returns 20 and DBAs will not increase this parameter.

Comment: *Why* doesn't explicitly closing the link (as that web page describes) work for you?

Comment: You use more than 20 db link at the same time ? Did you really tried the solution in the link telling to actively close those link after use?

Comment: in ORDS and APEX, we close all links at the end of each request for this reason. Otherwise #links allowed has to be size of conn pool + whatever overhead for the rest of the system.

Comment: @AlexPoole, we can not use commit or rollback in procedure since java side commits the transaction. so that solition doesn't work for us. and also to get rid of this problem we tried to use autonomous transaction but we got ORA-00164: distributed autonomous transaction disallowed within migratable distributed transaction.

Comment: @AxelH, i don't think so, db links are not closed so it reaches max limit soon

Comment: @ysnky - so why can't the Java side make another call to close the link after it commits?